# displaying the ELEMENT NAME that triggered mouse event in javascript

Tags: javascript, event-handling, ctrl

I'm trying to get the alert box to display the element name (here is html) (without hard-coding obviously) that triggered the event onclick with ctrl pressed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html onclick="alertD(event)">
<head>
<title>
</title>
</head>
<body>

<!--<p>click anywhere on the page to display alert dialog</p>-->



<script type="text/javascript">

function alertD(event) 
{
    if (event.shiftKey) 
    {
        alert(event);
    } 
    else if(event.ctrlKey) 
    {
        alert("html"); //-- this is where it would say something like alert(document.element)???
    }
    else
    {
        alert();
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at `event.target` - [Event Target](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_target.asp)

Comment: @George This is not a duplicate. That refers to looking at the object's constructor while this asking how to get the target element.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.target) property of the event to get the element. Then get the name of that element using [tagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.tagName) property of the element.

```
function alertD(event) 
{
    if (event.shiftKey) 
    {
        alert(event);
    } 
    else if(event.ctrlKey) 
    {
        alert(event.target.tagName); // <-- tag name
    }
    else
    {
        alert();
    }
}
```